# How to pass values of selected dropdown option but that dropdown is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application there is one dropdown it should be disabled .but when that dropdown making disable then selected value of that dropdown show in controller as null .instaed of disabled dropdown i am try to make that dropdown as readonly.here is the code how to make that dropdown as readonly.

`$('#IandS').attr("readonly", "readonly");`

but the problem is that on clicking on that dropdown .that dropdown is open to select another option. 
what is solution to access the values of disabled dropdown.
Please Suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access all DOM elements, no matter if `<select>` is disabled. I think you are getting the values from `<select>` directly, but if select is disabled it doesn't have any value!! It's because it returns null. To get the `<option>` tags you can make this:

```
$('#IandS').find('option').each(function() {
    console.log("Text: "+ $(this).text()+" -- Value: "+ $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Disabled inputs of Form never submits with Form

**For Solution**
you can make hidden field. and you can set selected value in hidden field as value.

1) Keep name if hidden field which you need on server side.

2) Remove name attribute from dropdown.

3) Add below code in javascript for apply changed value into hidden field

```
$('#IandS').change(function(){
   $('#hidden_field_id').val($(this).val());
});
```

I hope it should be help to you.